# subplot. Построение графиков в одном масштабе

Tags: python

Есть простой пример. Задача построить графики таким образом, чтобы оси абсцисс имели свой единый масштаб. Оси ординат соответственно тоже.

```
!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(-10, 10.01, 0.01)
y=np.arange(-5, 5.01, 0.01)

#subplot 1
plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot(x, np.sin(x))
plt.title(r'$\sin(x)$')
plt.grid(True)

#subplot 2
plt.subplot(212)
#plt.plot(x, np.cos(x), 'g')
plt.plot(y, np.cos(y), 'g')
plt.axis('equal')
plt.grid(True)

plt.title(r'$\cos(y)$')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы сделать оси одинаковыми можно воспользоваться `sharex` и `sharey` парметром при создании `subplot`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(-10, 10.01, 0.01)
y = np.arange(-5, 5.01, 0.01)

# subplot 1
ax = plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot(x, np.sin(x))
plt.title(r'$\sin(x)$')
plt.grid(True)

# subplot 2
plt.subplot(212, sharex=ax, sharey=ax)
plt.plot(y, np.cos(y), 'g')
plt.grid(True)

plt.title(r'$\cos(y)$')
plt.show()
```